# Read the image source path from a text file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have to display a sequence of images as a slideshow. I will have the path of the images in a text file. How read the image path from a text file ? Right now I have a hardcoded code like below:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>
```

Example text file with image paths:

https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1/folder1/folder2/sample.jpg

Comment: HTML alone cannot do this, use Javascript. Host your urls.txt on your server http://example.com/urls.txt, then request the URL with Ajax and parse the response.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to store your urls in a `JSON` encoded file, and use `fetch` to retrieve it.

Imagine, you have the following `JSON` file in your server :

```
"[
"https://placekitten.com/408/287",
"https://placekitten.com/200/286",
"https://placekitten.com/200/139"
]"
```

You can retrieve the file using `fetch`, and operate with the resulting `array` of urls, to populate your slideshow :

```
fetch('http://example.com/yourFile.json')
.then(function(response){
    // parse the fetch response
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson){
    // do whatever you need with the image paths array...
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to my comment, you request a URL and then parse the response and do something with it not with **HTML** but with **Javascript**.

We start by waiting for the document to load.

- After the the document loads, we wait for a button click.
- When button is clicked we Fetch a URL,  in your case a http://example.com/file.txt text file.
- We then grab the body text by using response.text(), now we can do something with it such as add the response to the results div.

Fetch Documentation: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
// When document is loaded and ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    // On button click initiate
    $("button").click(function(){
        // Request URL, change to http://example.com/file.txt
        fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                // Log body text
                console.log(data);
                // Set #results text to body text
                $('#results').text(data);
            })
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="results"></div>
  <button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must understand that javascript alone can't access other files in your server there will always be a need for php weather you implement ajax or not so here is a php example asssuming you have a text file `urls.txt` with the following contents

`https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1/folder1/folder2/sample.jpg`

```php
//Get the contents of the text file
$text = file_get_contents("path/to/urls.txt");

//Split them by the seperate lines
$textArr = explode("\n",$text);

//loop through the array
for($i = 0; $i < count($textArr); $i++){
  //Echo the images
  echo "<img src='" . $textArr[$i] . "' style='width:100%'>";
}
```

Comment: This is PHP part.. what are the changes I need to do I HTML to access these images ?

Comment: Inside the for loop you will notice the html is after echo @user2727765